# How to merge these two data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames DF1, DF2 that I want to merge on certain conditions.
They are both indexed by dates, but of different lengths.
I want to get a data frame similar to DF1 but where for a given date the value is modified to the value of DF2 if and only if there is a value for the same date in DF2.

From

```
DF1
                 v        
2014-01-02   0.580550
2014-01-03  -1.961033
2014-01-04   2.063441
2014-01-05   0.319570
2014-01-06   1.318068
```

And

```
DF2
              v        
2014-01-02   10.0
2014-01-03   14.0
2014-01-06   -5.3
```

Get

```
DF
                    v        
    2014-01-02   10.0
    2014-01-03   14.0
    2014-01-04   2.063441
    2014-01-05   0.319570
    2014-01-06   -5.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
DF = DF2.combine_first(DF1)
print (DF)
                    v
2014-01-02  10.000000
2014-01-03  14.000000
2014-01-04   2.063441
2014-01-05   0.319570
2014-01-06  -5.300000
```